# Hidden overflow on elements with variable height?

Tags: javascript, css, height, overflow

Is it possible to have element with height 100% so that it stretches on the page, to also have overflow hidden attribute so when content of that element gets too large, it wont go beyond that set height and respects overflow hidden?

In the example I use span inside the  element, because overflow works only in blocks.

[here is an example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWMwH/)

if its not possible by default, is there some possible hack to this? Maybe with javascript to detect height and feed it back to elements?

it doesn't need to be IE compatible, its for browser extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I in the end used is javascript = window.innerHeight to detect height

also example should have been maybe this
http://jsfiddle.net/EWMwH/2/

where we can actually see that middle part is stretching to oblige content and does not respect set height 100% and overflow.

And seems to me that it doesnt matter that I first time pasted whole document and not just body in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It works fine to use overflow on an element with variable sizing.

You have put a complete HTML document in jsfiddle, and it will then wrap that inside another HTML document, so your page will be broken.

Comment: I don't follow, html document? You mean element? And I have the text wrapped in a span but it wont get broken unless I declare height...

Comment: @DoTheEvo: What goes in the HTML pane in jsfiddle should be only the content of the body element, but you have put a complete HTML document there, so the final page has duplicates of the html, head and body tags.